# iphone simulator not starting

Tags: ios5, ios-simulator, xcode4.2

Freshly installed xcode 4.2 on snow leopard and my system profile reads:

Version:    4.2 (4C199)
Location:   /Developer

Applications:
  Xcode:    4.2 (828)
  Instruments:  4.2 (4233)
  Dashcode: 3.0.2 (336)

SDKs:
  Mac OS X:  10.6:  (10K549)
  iPhone OS:  5.0:  (9A334)
  iPhone Simulator:  5.0:   (9A334)

My apps work fine on the device but not on the simulator. Message on the xcode reads "Running  on iPhone 5.0 simulator" but simulator's status is "Application not responding". I even tried reinstalling xcode/sdk (--mode=all) but no luck.

I'm sure the problem is not with the app because the simulator doesnt respond even when I start it directly without xcode.

Comment: You can check this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12152559/ios-simulator-does-not-run/18820000#18820000