# iOS Simulator does not run

Tags: ios, xcode, sdk

I have a serious problem with the latest iOS Simulator.
I am using macbook pro, Mountain Lion OS, and xCode 4.4.1. which is the latest OS and the latest xCode.

When I run sample code to test iOS Simulator, the simulator will open but it will freeze.
The application does not respond, but stay on black screen, freezing. I've redownload xcode and reinstall it many times, it still doesn't work. can someone help me? 
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6):

Clear out the Simulator's data and apps by removing everything in `~/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/`. This will remove all existing user apps, which may well solve your problem.

Answer (score 2):

You can also fix it using resetting simulator. See below steps

**-> Select your simulator**

**-> In menu select iOS simulator**

**-> Click on reset content and settings...**

All you have done. :-)

Answer (score 0):

I just ran into simulator "does not work" problem. It was working on my previous application.
I can compile target 5.0 and run on iPhone 6.1 simulator.
But for some reason this new application does not show up on simulator at all. So install 5.0 simulator and now it is working on simulator 5.0.